# Int value not updating CALayer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, int

I have an int instance variable declared like this

```
@interface myLayer : CALayer{
    int compareValue;
}
```

Than in my layer's .m file I do

```
-(void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef) context{
compareValue ++;
NSLog(@"%i",compareValue);
}
```

However `compareValue` is always 0!!!

Why is not it updating???

Comment: That should work.  There must be something you are not telling us.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure when you are creating a `myLayer` instance you are actually using your custom class NOT the `CALayer` class ?